# laravel installing with composer in xampp in window 7

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

composer is installed successfully. but when I try to install laravel it shows this

> Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
>   Retrying with degraded mode

Answer (score 3):

```
composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

then try again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MichaelChirico This **does** provide an answer to the question. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/composer-update-very-very-slow-not-completing/?page=2 and https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4272

Comment: it seems better suited as a comment, is all.

Comment: thank your for your respond. it did not work. it did not show anythig. any more suggestions?